# Datetick show every year MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a plot and when using datetick it only shows a couple of years. I want that the x-axis show every year.

Note that x consists of daily obs and I want to show the axis only per year (but keeping the obs daily)

I tried:

```
figure;
bar(x, y, 'Stack'); 
datetick('x', 'yyyy', 'keeplimits', 'keepticks');
set(gca,'XTick', unique(year(x)) )
```

But this removes all the ticks on the x-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this get you started:

```
% sample data
x = datetime - 10000:datetime;
y = sin(1:10001);

figure;
bar(x, y, 'Stack'); 

% compute datetime array with each year
range       = unique(year(x));
yearticks   = datetime(range,ones(size(range)),ones(size(range)));

% update figure
set(gca, 'XTick', yearticks)
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 90)
```

Using `unique(year(x))` directly in the call to `set` will not work since it will return a `double` array, not a `datetime` array. The ticks will be way off the displayed axis limits and thus will not be visible.

Note: the ticks will mark January 1st of each year. If you want to mark the middle of a year, you need to adjust the call to `datetime` in the line that creates `yearticks`.

Comment: Thanks. getting the error While setting the 'XTick' property of 'Axes':
Value must be a vector of type single or double whose values increase

Comment: What release do you use? Since datetime arrays were introduced not so long ago, maybe your version does not support using set in this way. Workaround (did not test it yet): convert the `yearticks` to datenumbers: `yearticks = datenum(yearticks)` before setting 'XTick'. Let me know if it works, I will then update my answer.